# Can I navigate from a pivot table back to the original database?

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

Once I am "in" a pivot sheet, is there an easy way to click on a row or cell in the Pivot table and navigate directly back to the related data in the original database (Google Sheet), from which the Pivot table was derived. The use case would be a pivot table showing, for example, just the name of a salesperson and what territory s/he was assigned, clicking on the salesperson name would take you back to that row, or the first of the rows that included the salesperson's name and all the other data (columns/fields) in the original Google Sheet (database).

Answer (score 1):

Pivot table jumps are just one-way ticket rides. These options are closest you can get:

- usage of hotkey shortcuts to jump on next/previous sheet tab:

  - **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>** + **<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>** + **<kbd>PAGE UP</kbd>**
  - **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>** + **<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>** + **<kbd>PAGE DOWN</kbd>**
- delete pivot table view sheet (in some cases)
- placing "return hyperlink" or "return hyperlink button"
- and ofcourse manual navigation