# Link row in a pivot table back to the source record (in an adjacent Google sheet)

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

I have two (Google) sheets; the first contains the raw data (records/rows) and the latter a pivot table derived from those records. I want to use the pivot table to index the critical fields and then link back to the original (full) record in a manner that won't require the viewer to have to navigate/sort the raw data.

I did find this:

[Can I navigate from a pivot table back to the original database?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/127732/can-i-navigate-from-a-pivot-table-back-to-the-original-database)

But the post doesn't seem to answer the question precisely... and it was a few years ago so I'm wondering if there is a way to add this by hyperlinking individual records (in a Google sheet) and adding their fields to the adjacent pivot table?

Comment: Hello! I don't know how your source data nor your pivot table are organized, but maybe you can set a new column next to the pivot table with a formula that concatenates some string through some MATCH formulas to find the original cells and create an URL to a Hyperlink. And create something like this: https://www.howtogeek.com/780305/how-to-get-a-hyperlink-to-a-cell-or-range-in-google-sheets/ - if you add more information, I can try to go a little further

Comment: Maybe ask @user0 to expand on what they meant by ***placing "return hyperlink" or "return hyperlink button"*** [in their answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/127735/).  They are an active user and the question does seem to be close enough that it is better to improve the question and answer, than have multiple versions floating around and cross link.

Comment: Thanks for your responses! I have two sheets, the first containing the raw data (records/rows) the latter with the pivot table derived from those records. I want to use the pivot table to index the critical fields and then link back to the original (full) record. The post I referenced initially mentions placing "return hyperlink" but I'm guessing this is just a link back to the (entire) raw data sheet. I was hoping that there might be a way I can create a reference to a specific record within the pivot table itself; I'll take a look @Martin 's link and see if I can do this for individual rows.

Comment: @Martin: I've also updated the original question with a bit more info. If it helps, once I get this answered here, I'll link this question to the post I referenced in my question.

Comment: Hello! What I was meaning was to create a Hyperlink to a specific row within that raw sheet. You want to "expand" inside the pivot table sheet the fields that are not included from just one row you choose?, Like some kind of dashboard?? It is possible with some ingenuity, but I suggest you attach something a little more representative of your original spreadsheet. Maybe one with some sample data? Or/and a picture of what you want to look like the final result

Comment: Hi, welcome to WebApps. Your question is inconsistent: Para#1 (Pivot to Raw data): "use the pivot table to index the critical fields and then link back to the original (full) record" vs Para#3 (Raw Data to Pivot): "hyperlinking individual records (in a Google sheet) and adding their fields to the adjacent pivot table". Also it is hypothetical, no data or example. So far as the referenced question is concerned, I thought it answered your question without any equivocation: [Pivot table jumps are just one-way ticket rides.](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/127735/196152)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I navigate from a pivot table back to the original database?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/127732/can-i-navigate-from-a-pivot-table-back-to-the-original-database)